# ¿Cómo puedo detectar las redes wifi cercanas con Python?

Tags: python, wifi

Estoy intentando detectar las redes wifi cercanas con Python, utilizo este código:

```
from wifi import Cell
for cell in Cell.all('wlan0'): print(cell.ssid)
```

Pero obtengo este error:

> ```
>    Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\meics\Desktop\DylanT\VSC-PROYECTS\Python\game.py", line 2,
> in <module>
>     for cell in Cell.all('wlan0'): print(cell.ssid)   File  "C:\Users\meics\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\wifi\scan.py",
> line 38, in all
>     iwlist_scan = subprocess.check_output(['/sbin/iwlist', interface, 'scan'],   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 420, in check_output
>     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 501, in run
>     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:   File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 947, in __init__
>     self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "C:\Program
> Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.496.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 1416, in _execute_child
>     hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el
> archivo
> ```

Tengo todo lo necesario instalado, pero no me funciona.

¿Me podrían ayudar a solucionar este error o hacerlo de otra forma?

Comment: `/sbin/iwlist` es un programa **de linux**. Tu estás ejecutando **en Windows**.

Comment: estoy en windows

Comment: Lo se. Se ve claramente en los errores.

Comment: entonces no hay una libreria para ver las redes wifi cercanas en windows?

Comment: Ni idea. Me limito a señalarte los elementos clave de los mensajes de error que has mostrado.

Comment: Puedes revisar [este post](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2017/06/22/viewing-wireless-networks-with-powershell-legacy-commands.aspx) para orientarte sobre cómo ejecutar estas funciones con PowerShell, ya que tienen soporte nativo. Es otra opción que tienes. Puedes consultar también [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41692077/using-python-to-get-the-powershell-result#41692177) (en inglés) sobre cómo integrar Python y PowerShell (datos de salida).

Comment: Hay librerías para usar WiFi directamente en Python, sin necesidad de ejecutar procesos externos. Google "Python WiFi" y selecciona la alternativa de tu conveniencia.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo directamente con subprocesos

```
import subprocess
redes= subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
print(redes)
```

Esto da una lista con un poco mas de información de las redes, si quieres solo los nombres usa:

```
import subprocess
redes= subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
ls=redes.split("\n")
ssids = [v.strip() for k, v in (p.split(':') for p in ls if 'SSID' in p)]
print(ssids)
```

Si quieres las ssids enumeradas cambia la linea de `ssids =` por:

```
ssids = [k for k in ls if 'SSID' in k]
```

O utiliza un for para enumerarlas a tu gusto, ejemplo con enumeracion personalizada:

```
import subprocess
redes= subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "network"], capture_output=True, text=True).stdout
ls=redes.split("\n")
ssids = [v.strip() for k, v in (p.split(':') for p in ls if 'SSID' in p)]
print("Redes disponibles: ")
cont=1
for i in ssids:
  print("Red",cont,": ",i) #i=nombre de red, cont=usado para enumerar
  cont+=1 #es lo mismo que usar cont=cont+1
  red_elegida=input("Seleccione el numero de red a elegir:")
```

Comment: sería bueno detallar que hacer el método `run` al igual que sus parámetros, igual debes de decir que usas una *list comprehension* e indicar la lógica de eso para que , encaso se quiera, se pueda optar por un `for` normal

Comment: @Christian, los argumentos usados no creí que fueran necesarios incluirlos ya que se preguntaba por algo muy especifico, no es necesario explicar la lógica de la lista ya que con un simple "for i in ssids: print(i)" (en el caso de querer usar el for mencionado) seria suficiente, en el caso de la variable ls olvide quitarla del primer codigo, pero si se quiere usar dicha variable para imprimir la lista seria algo raro ya que la propia variable de ssids hace el trabajo de depurar los datos no necesarios

Comment: y tu como sabes que el autor de la pregunta conoce todo lo que mencionas? Recuerda que la respuesta es para todos y no solo pare el autor

Comment: mencione que con un for podrian imprimir a su gusto los nombres, estoy suponiendo que sabe los temas fundamentales de python

Comment: y en caso no lo sepa o no entienda bien los ciclos?

Comment: vamos a ver, esta usando el modulo wifi, supongo que esta tratando de hacer un wifi cracker o un analizador de redes probablemente, no es un proyecto en el que trabajas si no entiendes teoria basica del lenguaje, por eso omito detalles poco significantes como un for

Comment: yo quise ser hacker sin saber programar \\_(°-°)_/, lo que quiero que entiendas es que las respuestas siempre deben ser detalladas ya que son **para todos**

Comment: buen punto ahí me ganaste, y hablando de eso, gente que lea este mini debate si quieren hackear, en primera no lo hagan, en segunda, estudien seguridad de TI mejor, en todo caso en unos momentos agrego esa info ntp